# Git: Communication between boilerplate and ongoing projects

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, gitkraken

I run several projects that share the same base. So, at some point in time I decided to extract the boilerplate out of them. After extracting I'd like to make it public and to keep all other projects private.

```
Boilerplate (public)
|
|- Project 1 (private)
|- Project 2 (private)
```

Is it possible to do in somewhat fool-proof way? For instance, I shouldn't be able to push into boilerplate stuff from private branches. And maybe you have experience doing something similar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do use a similar workflow for some projects and my "fool-proof" safeguard is to prompt for password when pushing to boilerplate to ensure I know what I'm doing.

I use SSH keys for all my projects. However, when I want to base off a boilerplate, I instead clone from boilerplate using the https url naming the remote "upstream" then add the private project remote "origin" as SSH.

When I'm working on the private projects, I make commits and push normally over SSH without password. Occasionally I make some updates that would be useful in the boilerplate, so I checkout a new branch "boilerplate" set to track upstream/master and cherry-pick those backports from master. Then I `git push upstream boilerplate:master` and since it's an https url I then get prompted for password. This has worked well for me as an idiot check because I push so often without password that the prompt gives me a chance to cancel if it's a mistake.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to adapt your solutions to my workflow. As I'm using GitKraken and not just console, I have to make several push-scrips and learn how to use them (I suppose).

BTW, hope I'm not being super dumb here, but how do you force github to ask for password? I'm never being asked.